# Can you knock a Banshee unconscious?

Tags: dnd-5e, undead, conditions, unconscious, incorporeal

In our campaign I am attempting to garner information about a spellbook from a Banshee. I've had some suggestions from NPCs to beguile it, but trying to cover all my bases, I wondered if I could knock it out and interrogate it. I asked my DM if I could knock a Banshee out, and he said that he didn't know. Is it up to the DM's discretion, or is there a set answer?

Answer (score 8):

MM p.23 says this about Banshees and conditions (spoiler-ified because your character might not have any way of knowing these things):

> **Condition Immunities** charmed, exhaustion, frightened, grappled, paralyzed, petrified, poisoned, prone, restrained

That list doesn't contain *unconscious* so they are subject to that condition and, in theory, you can knock them out in the usual way and according to PHB p.198:

> When an attacker reduces a creature to 0 hit points with a melee attack, the attacker can knock the creature out.

Good luck surviving long enough to knock her out if you're playing Phandelver, a Banshee is not to be trifled with when you're a low level party. And keep in mind that a Banshee cannot be restrained so double-plus good luck tying one up while you interrogate her. You're probably better off placating her and offering gifts.

Comment: By this line of logic wouldn't it also mean that creatures that *are* immune to "unconscious"  (for example poltergeist and fire elemental) would be unaffected by being reduced to 0 hit points (other than that they start rolling death saving throws)?

Comment: Sounds like the start of a great, seperate, question.

Comment: @JonatanHedborg That looks like a gray area to me so DM's discretion. Also, a lot of DMs don't bother with the whole death save process for monsters.